# MySQL - Obtener el tiempo que estuvo activo

Tags: mysql, sql

Queridos expertos en MySQL,

Estoy intentando, realizar una vista donde reste 2 fechas y obtenga el tiempo que estuvo en activo todos los eventos según cada idevento. No veo nada de luz y he entrado en bucle fustrandome demasiado.

En resumen, sin querer liar a nadie, quiero obtener el tiempo en segundos que estuvo cada (idevento) a 1.
Quedaría como la tabla de la derecha pero con la columna (durationseconds) con el valor correspondiente.

Por ejemplo:

id-----fechaini-------------idevento-estado-bituno

29-----14/02/2021 15:13:22-----4-------0-------1

27-----14/02/2021 15:11:31-----4-------1-------1

Debería resultar:

fechaini--------------idevento-----estado---bituno----durationseconds

14/02/2021 15:11:31------4-----------1---------1-----------111

Y así sucesivamente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mil gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

No logro entender bien como obtendrás la fecha final pero si buscas obtener la diferencia de horas o minutos entre dos fechas te puede servir algo como esto:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, fechaini , fechafin) as horas FROM eventos;
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fechaini ,fechafin) as minutos FROM eventos;

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,"2020-02-18 12:00:00", "2020-02-18 12:30:00");

Salida: 30
```

De igual forma te adjunto mi fuente de Mysql de donde eh obtenido bastantes combinaciones cuando se trata de fechas.

[Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)